# Asterisk - Using realtime to store extension contexts

Tags: mysql, asterisk

I would like to be able setup an Asterisk service where users can self register and create their own numbers. I was hoping to use extension contexts to achieve the actual partitioning of accounts. However the only way I can see to do this is by editing the extensions.conf file and manually restarting the service.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to achieve this by using Realtime? I have seen various patches, etc but they are all very old and never made it into a stable release.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any need in patches.

All that chnages in asterisk core since 1.4 version.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Extensions

But that will not work very effective

Very likly you need hire expert who do it correctly via db lookups/dialplan.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I would prefer to set this up myself. Do you have any example links you could post?

Comment: There are examples at page above. But that is theory only. For realy working system you have REALY understand how it work INTERNALY. So if you are not expert, you have high chance system will be not usable under load. If you load < 5 CPS, you can do it via realtime without issues.